# Can't build on Android anymore

Tags: codenameone

I can't build my app anymore.

I could do it this afternoon, but tonight it crashes on Codename One server

> Dex: The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>   Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>
> com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

On another topic I read I can put "codename1.arg.android.multidex=true" in properties.

After that I can build my app but Google reject if because "the debug mode is enable".

What should I do ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Android was launched with a 64k method limit and slowly ballooned in part due to Google Play Services. As a solution Google introduced multi-dex which makes the build slightly slower but adds support for more methods. You can enable it for your Codename One app with the build hint:

```
android.multidex=true
```

Comment: If I add it Google reject my apk, telling me I must disable debug mode /

Comment: You need to make release builds, multidex has nothing to do with it. Check that you defined an Android certificate and make sure release is checked in Codename One Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I added `codename1.arg.android.debug=false` and Google accept the apk. It's strange : I could built and send my app to Google last two years without that. Anyway, it works, I'm happy =)